# SQL Server Pattern Match with the FROM part of a Select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008. The title is difficult to understand, but here is what I have:

```
A  B        C
-----------------    
1  Apple    A11
2  Bannana  BBB
3  Cat      CD1
```

I want the output of the select statement to look like this:

```
A  B        C     D
--------------------    
1  Apple    A11   1
2  Bannana  BBB   0
3  Cat      CD1   1
```

D=1 if C=A## or if C=CD#, otherwise D=0

So, it needs to be something in the select like this:

```
Select
    A, B, C,
    **"some way here to do pattern matching" AS D**
From....
```

Comment: You can use `CASE` statements. SQL does not have pattern matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when c like 'A[0-9][0-9]' or c like 'CD[0-9]'
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from t;
```

I am interpreting the `#` as a digit.  For any character, use underscore instead of the `[0-9]`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, exactly what I was looking for!